# Calculate gradient of data in R (or other)

Tags: r

I have temperature data over the period of 30 minutes taken at 32Hz.
I'd like to calculate the local rate of change of the temperature. I apologise, I don't know how to make a proper reproducible data set. It would need a vector Time with values the same for 32 points, then increases by 1 second.

```
   P1_test<- data.frame(
        Time = sample(1:32:1),
        Temperature = rnorm(32)
    )
 ycs.prime <- diff(P1_test$Temperature)/diff(P1_test$Time)
 pred.prime <- predict(spl, deriv=1)
```

I get infs and 0s because Deltat is 0 most of the time, apart from the step change between seconds. What do you suggest?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend making a **reproducible example**. If you know your data is at 32Hz but the recorded times are rounded to the nearest second (or floored?) I'd recommend you either (a) average the temps that have the same time together or (b) (if they're in the correct order and you know the measurements to be reliably at 32Hz) edit the data to add more precision.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot work out how to make the data to fit this example,  please accept my apologies. I do understand what you suggest though. The measurements are definitely 32Hz. What do you mean by add more precision by editing the data?

Comment: If you have times `1, 1, 1, 1, 1` add `0` to the first one, `1/32` to the next, `2/32` to the next, and so on, so that you have the true time rather than some rounded time. As far as data to fit the example, `dput(head(your_data, 40))` would probably be just fine. Put a `droplevels()` inside the `dput` too if you have factors that make the output too long.

Comment: where does spl come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Gregor points out, you need a more fine-grained representation of your time variable if you want to look at how temperature changes by time. There are two solutions. The best option is **if your data are ordered in the order they were recorded** (so the first row was the first measurement, second row second measurement, etc.) then use the ordering information to make a more detailed version of your time variable:

```
> # there are 1800 seconds in 30 minutes, 32 measurements per second
> Seconds <- as.numeric(gl(n=1800, k=32, labels=1:1800))
> Temp <- rnorm(57600)
> df <- data.frame(Seconds, Temp)
> head(df) # the first 6 rows
  Seconds       Temp
1       1 -0.9543326
2       1  0.1973152
3       1 -0.4815007
4       1 -0.2494005
5       1  0.7282253
6       1 -1.0690358
> tail(df) # the last 6 rows
      Seconds         Temp
57595    1800 -0.708576762
57596    1800  2.660348850
57597    1800 -0.003186668
57598    1800  0.025776665
57599    1800 -1.627054312
57600    1800  0.241060762
> 
> ycs.prime <- diff(df$Temp)/diff(df$Seconds) # doesn't work properly
> 
> head(ycs.prime, 35) # first 35 elements
 [1]        Inf       -Inf        Inf        Inf       -Inf       -Inf        Inf       -Inf
 [9]       -Inf        Inf       -Inf        Inf       -Inf       -Inf        Inf       -Inf
[17]       -Inf        Inf        Inf        Inf       -Inf        Inf       -Inf        Inf
[25]       -Inf       -Inf        Inf       -Inf        Inf        Inf       -Inf -0.2423703
[33]        Inf        Inf       -Inf
>
```

Again, **assuming the rows in your data frame are the correct order the measurements were taken in**, you can add a Time variable that is just the order of the measurements. It will run from 1 (first measurement) to 57600 (the last measurement). Assuming the measurements are taken at regular intervals, the units for this variable are 1/32 of a second.

```
> df$Time <- 1:nrow(df)
> 
> head(df)
  Seconds       Temp Time
1       1 -0.9543326    1
2       1  0.1973152    2
3       1 -0.4815007    3
4       1 -0.2494005    4
5       1  0.7282253    5
6       1 -1.0690358    6
> tail(df)
      Seconds         Temp  Time
57595    1800 -0.708576762 57595
57596    1800  2.660348850 57596
57597    1800 -0.003186668 57597
57598    1800  0.025776665 57598
57599    1800 -1.627054312 57599
57600    1800  0.241060762 57600
> 
> ycs.prime <- diff(df$Temp)/diff(df$Time)
> plot(ycs.prime, type = "l")
```

[image: temperature change]

Want to convert this variable to a more easily interpretable unit?

```
> df$Time <- df$Time/32 # now it's in seconds
```

**If you're not sure that the rows are in order,** then you don't actually have information at 32Hz, you have 32 samples from each second but you don't know what order they came in. The best you can do there is to average the 32 samples you have for each second to get one more reliable measure per second, and then look at change in temperature second to second.

```
> # again, same initial data frame
> Seconds <- as.numeric(gl(n=1800, k=32, labels=1:1800))
> Temp <- rnorm(57600)
> df <- data.frame(Seconds, Temp)
> 
> # average Temp for each Second
> df$Temp <- ave(df$Temp, df$Seconds, FUN = mean)
> head(df) # note it's the same for the whole first second
  Seconds      Temp
1       1 0.1811943
2       1 0.1811943
3       1 0.1811943
4       1 0.1811943
5       1 0.1811943
6       1 0.1811943
> df <- unique(df) # drop repeated rows
> nrow(df) # one row per second
[1] 1800
> 
> ycs.prime <- diff(df$Temp)/diff(df$Seconds)
> plot(ycs.prime, type = "l")
```

[image: temperature change by second]

Comment: Nice write-up! Lots of detail :)

Comment: Thanks! It's all your suggestions from your comments, but I thought it might solve OP's problem to have it laid out with examples.

Comment: Thank very much @RoseHartman ! I really appreciate your effort in the detail and the graphs too. Do you think it's worth putting the temperature data through a filter of some sort to remove "erroneous" sudden spikes? E.g. to smooth it out a bit... It's skin temperature that's being measured, so there really shouldn't be any spikes.

Comment: @HCAI, glad I could help! You're talking now about outlier removal, which is a different question entirely. There are lots of great guidelines for how to go about that, including for densely sampled repeated measures like yours (for example, check out EEG data processing, such as https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26737359).

Comment: @RoseHartman Ah, thank you for the link! In fact the skin temp. measurements are actually done at the same time as EEG. So it will definitely come in handy!